# Find the number of generators for $(\mu_{25}, .)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

Find the number of generators for $(\mu_{25}, .)$

I know that $\bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ is a generator iff the $\gcd(a, n)=1$. So as I understand there is 20 generators. I know that $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}  \cong (\mu_{25}, .)$.

Will I have 20 generators as well for $\mu_{25}$? In other words, I would like to know if the number of generator are preserved between $(\mu_{25}, .)$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$.

**Definition:** $\mu_n = \left \{ e^{\frac{2 k \pi i}{n}} : 1 \leq k \leq 24 \right\}$

Comment: What is $\mu_{25}$?

Comment: $\mu_n = \{ e^{\frac{2 k \pi i}{n}} : 1 \leq k \leq 24 \}$

Comment: What is the link between "So as I understand there is $20$ generators" and "will I have $25$ generators as well for $\mu_{25}$ ?"

Comment: I would like to know if the number of generators is preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have $\varphi(25)=20$ generators. Isomorphisms preserve both the orders of the groups and the orders of their elements. Also, generators are mapped onto generators; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930683/104041) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1902741/104041)